# What does 「ことにならあね」 mean?

Tags: meaning

> 路{ろ｝上{じょう}でたたき売{う}りしようが　こそドロやろうがめんどうみようって**ことにならあね**。

What does 「ことにならあね」 mean? Is it equivalent to 「ことにならない」？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「(~って)ことにならあね」

I think it's slurred 「(~という)ことになる+わ(や)+ね」
i.e. 「(~という)ことになる(だろう)よ・よね」

For example:

> 酒がまずくならあ！ ≒ 酒がまずくなる(よ/わ)！