# What is the meaning of ならあね in なるようにならあね！

Tags: colloquial-language

How should the sentence ending in 「なるようにならあね!」 be interpreted? Is it a slurred ならない? If that is the case it seems like an unusual choice to write the write the line like this.

For reference, here is a timestamped video where the ending is used:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYONjkBu6u0&t=1084s

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does 「ことにならあね」 mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24782/what-does-%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8%e3%81%ab%e3%81%aa%e3%82%89%e3%81%82%e3%81%ad-mean) なるようになる is an idiom, so you should be able to find its definition easily.

Comment: Yes thank you, that is a great help!