# What is the meaning of ハリ倒したらァ!

Tags: colloquial-language

> ヤキ入れて追放に決まってんだろ！ハリ倒したらァ！

What is the meaning of 「ハリ倒したらァ」 here? As far as I am aware 「～らぁ」 can be a change from 「～るわ」 holding a meaning similar to 「～るよ」 as in this question: [What does 「ことにならあね」 mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24782/30454)

Assuming that this is such a change, that would make the underlying sentence「張り倒したるわ」, and my best guess is this would mean 「張り倒してやるよ」 but I really don't know. What is the actual meaning here?

Comment: Can't it be a simple conditional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's short for 張り倒してやるわ.

- -てやる contracts to -たる. For the meaning of this やる, see [What does てやる mean when it is not used for giving?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14413/5010) and [What does the word 「やったる」mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36744/5010)
- This やらぁ is perhaps originally やるわ (where [わ is a *masculine* sentence-end particle](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/35800/5010)), but it's now fundamentally a distinct sentence-ender used by rough speakers. It's similar to やるよ, やるぜ, etc., but much rougher. They also say ならぁ (~なるわ), but they don't say 取らぁ, 知らぁ, etc. I don't know why.

Comment: Alright great, thanks a lot for the clear and useful answer!