# What does Causative + たる mean?

Tags: contractions, subsidiary-verbs

The character girlfriend criticizes him and he says this:

> 俺が善がるだけしかできねぇってか!?

My reading is akin to "Are you say I only satisfy myself!?"

Then he later adds

> 死ぬほど善がらせたるわ!

From context I can gather he seemed to be saying he'll satisfy her needs to a crazy degree. But I don't this use of causative + たる. たる seems to be used after "noun" for capacity, but how is after a causative verb?

From context I can gather he may be saying "I'll show you I can also fulfill you needs/take care of you/etc"

Comment: たる here is a dialectal contraction of て + やる

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/92823/9831

Comment: So he's saying... I'm gonna let you satisfy yourself/Have a good time"?

Comment: Today, よがる is almost never used outside sexual contexts. If I guessed the context correctly, this よがる refers to "moaning and writhing" with sexual pleasure. Does that explain your question?